# Trying to Fix Slightly Different Rendering in IE8 of Same Page

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer-8

I have a page with a form that is showing up fine in one version of IE8 but slightly messed up when viewed in IE8 on another computer. You can see the image of the broken page here:

http://blog.freihofersrun.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/download1.jpg

I added a bit of CSS code to style.css that I found on this Web site for another issue, but that didn't fix it (adding body {margin-top: 0;} to the style sheet). Any other suggestions? Thanks much, Chris

Comment: Post some code so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

A method for fixing might be using "clear" CSS property for each input. Alternatively you can wrap each label-input pair with a div of 100% width (or what amount of width could keep it aligned properly) and of auto height.